# jquery mobile live function not working in using phone gap for android

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

jquery mobile live function not working in using phone gap for android .see my below code can anybody tell what is problem  I have included  jquery libray and phongap js can anybody tell what is problem ? and one more question is if this event is not fired how to fire default event in phone gap

<

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.css" type="text/css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css" type="text/css"/>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script>

       <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.js"></script>

$( function()
         {
 $("#body").live('swiperight', function() { 
        {
    alert( 'You swiped!' ); 
    return false;
        });
 });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('body').live('swiperight', function() { 
            alert( 'You swiped!' ); 
    return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra '{' after swiperight ....